# Can't connect to my node app / mongoDB - Proxy Error

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb

I am currently trying to enter the website I have been building with React, node.js and MongoDB, which is hosted locally, however when I try to login, I get the following error. Does anyone know what I can do to resolve. Today I am using a different wifi than the one I typically use - could this be the problem. So far, I've went to my mongoDB account and added this current IP address but it didn't resolve the issue?

This is a snippet of the error code:

[image]

This is the error message:

```
[1] 09:30:32 [vite] http proxy error at /v1/auth/login:
[1] Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5000
[1]     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
[0] MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
[0]     at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\Benjamin.Faulkner.GLOBALRESOURCES\Desktop\ProjectTracker2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:809:11)      
[0]     at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\Benjamin.Faulkner.GLOBALRESOURCES\Desktop\ProjectTracker2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:784:11)     
[0]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[0]     at async file:///C:/Users/Benjamin.Faulkner.GLOBALRESOURCES/Desktop/ProjectTracker2/server.js:44:3 {
[0]   reason: TopologyDescription {
[0]     type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
[0]     servers: Map(3) {
[0]       'ac-ulspjlz-shard-00-00.esp7x2u.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
[0]       'ac-ulspjlz-shard-00-01.esp7x2u.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
[0]       'ac-ulspjlz-shard-00-02.esp7x2u.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
[0]     },
[0]     stale: false,
[0]     compatible: true,
[0]     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
[0]     localThresholdMS: 15,
[0]     setName: 'atlas-aga9cy-shard-0',
[0]     maxElectionId: null,
[0]     maxSetVersion: null,
[0]     commonWireVersion: 0,
[0]     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
[0]   },
[0]   code: undefined
[0] }
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Hi, I've now updated it to include the pasted error message as well